# Ajax page loader not working in HTML object

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I tried the below way to display an Ajax loader image until page loads into `HTML object`. But it didn't work for me. What's the issue with below code? The code does everything but not displaying the Ajax loader image in the run time.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>mouseover image position</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    body
    {
    background-color:#aaaaff;
    }
    #one
    {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-150px 0 0 -250px;
    }
    object
    {
    width:500px; 
    height:300px; 
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    }
    /*//]]>*/
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    // written by: Coothead
    function updateObjectIframe(which){
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
    }

    //]]>
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#Layer10").show();
});
$.ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#Layer10").hide();
});
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="one">
    <object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://www.w3schools.com/">
    <div id="Layer10">
    <img id="loading-image" src="im/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />  
    </div>
    </object>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">this is an object test not an iframe test</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this happens because an **object** tag isn't seen as an AJAX request by the browser. I don't know if there's a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: This must be written in comment not answer.

Comment: Sorry. Still not very familiar with StackOverflow. Will keep it in mind.